# Insert SeekBar in custom AlertDialog (Android)

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am trying to use a SeekBar in a custom AlertDialog, but when i click the button it crashes.
The custom AlertDialog only has a TextView with the id "seekProgress" and a SeekBar with the id "seekBar1".
If i delete the "seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener..." it doesn't crash but of course nothing happens when i move it.

The main activity has a button with onClick="myMethod" where I make my AlertDialog. Here is the code for this method:

```
public void myMethod(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_exchange_money_farmers, null));
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekProgress);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressValue;
        TextView seekProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekProgress);

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressValue = progress;
            seekProgress.setText("Covered: " + progress + " / " + seekBar.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekProgress.setText("Covered: " + progressValue + " / " + seekBar.getMax());
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

How can I make the SeekBar Listener to work?

EDIT: When i debug i get this error:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference

I have `SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);` why does it say it is null?

SOLUTION:
I had to tell him in which layout were the items.

```
     View testView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_exchange_money_farmers, null);
        builder.setView(testView);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) testView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekProgress = (TextView) testView.findViewById(R.id.seekProgress);
```

Comment: btw, I can make it work in the main activity, but it doesn't work in the AlertDialog...

Comment: If you got logcat, please post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_exchange_money_farmers,null);
    builder.setView(view);
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekProgress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seekProgress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked logcat when the app crashes? Try making the seekbar and seekProgress variables global. and initialize them in onCreate method.

Comment: What is the error shown in logcat, when the app crashes?